# Geting fitBounds and removeLayers to work in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, popup, markers

I am making a Leaflet map that gets its marker and popup information from a database.

I have a dropdown that allows me to retrieve a subset of the entire database based on category. The drop-down and map work correctly.

I have 2 problems:

1. I have been unsuccessful getting fitBounds to work.
2. When the map loads a category of markers from the dropdown, I want any existing markers on the map from previous searches removed

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
<script src="leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.ajax.js"></script>
<title>Member Map</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="options">
    <?php
      $conn = new mysqli("localhost","","","") or die($this->mysqli->error);
      $result = $conn->query("SELECT Bus_categories FROM markers GROUP BY Bus_categories");
      echo "<form>";
      echo "<select name='cs' onchange='showUser (this.value)'>";
      echo "<option style='value=selected'>Select Business Category</option>";
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        unset($name);
        $name = $row['Bus_categories']; 
        echo '<option  value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
      }
      echo "</select></form>";
    ?>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var geojsonLayer;
    var bounds;
    var m = L.map('map').setView([39.1, -94.5], 8);
    var mopt = {
      url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<API KEY HERE>',
      options: {attribution:'© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'}
    };
    var mq = L.tileLayer(mopt.url,mopt.options);
    mq.addTo(m);

    function popUp(feature,layer) {
      layer.bindPopup(
        "<h2>"+feature.properties.Member_Name+
        "<h3>"+feature.properties.Address+
        "<br>"+feature.properties.City+
        "<br><br><a href=tel:"+feature.properties.Phone+ ">"+feature.properties.Phone+ "</a>" +
        "<br><br><a href=mailto:"+feature.properties.Email+ ">" +feature.properties.Email+ "</a>" +
        "<br><br><a href=http://"+feature.properties.Website+ ">" +feature.properties.Website+ "</a>" +
        "<br>"
      );
    }

    function showUser(str) {
      geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["geojson.php?cs="+str,true],{onEachFeature:popUp}).addTo(m);
      if(geojsonLayer){ m.removeLayer(geojsonLayer) };
      bounds = geojsonLayer.getBounds().pad(0.2);  
      m.fitBounds(bounds);      
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Here is an example of the geojson data the map is getting from geojson.php

```
 {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.905793,39.416633]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"Angels Rock Bar","Contact":"Pedro Lopez","Address":"1323 Walnut","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 896-3943","Email":"info@angelsrockbarkc.com","Website":"www.angelsrockbarkc.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.541461,39.051003]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"Bar K","Contact":"Leib Dodell","Address":"501 Berkley Parkway","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 225-6961","Email":"wag@barkdogpbar.com","Website":"www.barkdogbar.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.583506,39.098954]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"The Indie on Main","Contact":"Jamie Pitts","Address":"1228 Main St.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 283-9900","Email":"","Website":""}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.578476,39.091498]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"International Tap House (iTap)","Contact":"Jonathan Whitaker","Address":"403 E. 18th St.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 701-6606","Email":"beer@internationaltaphouse.com","Website":"www.internationaltaphouse.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.541461,39.051003]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"Kill Devil Club","Contact":"Scott Tipton","Address":"31 E.14th St.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 674-4137","Email":"","Website":"www.killdevilclub.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.603187,39.061865]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"The Monarch Bar, LLC","Contact":"Kenny Cohrs","Address":"4808 Roanoke Pkwy.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 437-7912","Email":"info@themonarchbar.com","Website":"www.themonarchbar.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.581677,39.098391]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"PBR Big Sky","Contact":"Will Kinser","Address":"111 E 13th St.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 442-8145","Email":"info@pbrbigskykc.com","Website":"www.pbrbigskykc.com"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-94.581637,39.097872]},"properties":{"Member_Name":"Shark Bar","Contact":"Elliot Duckworth","Address":"1340 Grand Blvd.","City":"Kansas City","Phone":"(816) 377-9442","Email":"elliot@sharkbarkc.com","Website":"www.sharkbarkc.com"}}]}
```

Comment: What are the error message? (Press F12 in Firefox or Chrome (?) and look at the console output.)

Comment: Please see my comment about errors to @Francisco

Answer (score 1):

The variable `geojsonLayer` is local to the function `showUser`. Each time `showUser` is called (when the select changes) the value of geojsonLayer will NOT be, the previous layer that you use.

An easy solution for your currently code is convert `geojsonLayer` to be global variable.

And use `removeLayer` instead of `clearLayers`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geojsonLayer;  // outside any function it will be global
    var m= L.map('map').setView([39.1, -94.5], 8);

    ...


    function showUser(str) {
        if (geojsonLayer) {
            m.removeLayer(geojsonLayer);  // Remove the object from the map
        }
        geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(["geojson.php?cs="+str,true],{onEachFeature:popUp})
        geojsonLayer.addTo(m);
        var bounds = geojsonLayer.getBounds().pad(0.2);  // Extend the bounds a a 10%. Take care if the layer is a single point. Should be a local var
        m.fitBounds(bounds);
     }
```

Comment: I updated the code I originally posted to include your code. The console did not show any errors on page load but when I attempt to choose a select, no markers appear and the console shows a TypeError for removeLayer, showUser and onchange. These errors did not occur before addition of the code. I deleted the `removeLayer` and TypeErrors are the same except removeLayer points to 'leaflet-src.js' instead of where I added it. Still does not show any markers. Did I put the code in the wrong place?

Comment: The first time you call `showUser`, `geojsonLayer` would be empty. Thus you cannot remove it from the map. You can catch this by writing `if(geojsonLayer){m.removeLayer(geojsonLayer)}` as the first command of `showUser`.

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone I updated the code to include your suggestions. If all the code is included then no markers are shown and same TypeErrors as before. If I comment out the removeLayer statement I get markers but the fitBounds does not work and I get the same errors. If I comment out the bounds and just leave the removeLayer then I get no markers and no errors

Comment: I update my code. It will be usefull have the geojson that your are getting from your backend

Comment: I added some example geojson data the file above is getting when a category is selected from the drop down.